# How should I refactor/redesign my code

Tags: python, refactoring, duplicates

I'm writing a game in Python and I'm looking for some advice on how to redesign my code. Below is the definition of the movement component for a game entity.

The load function takes a PropertyTree object and sets the attributes of `self` accordingly. The save function does the opposite: based on the attributes of `self`, a PropertyTree is generated and returned.

```
class Movement(EntityComponent):
    def __init__(self):
        # Default values
        self.speed = 0
        self.acceleration = 0

    def load(self, properties):
        self.speed = int(properties['Speed'])
        self.acceleration = int(properties['Acceleration'])

    def save(self):
        pt = PropertyTree()
        pt['Speed'] = str(self.speed)
        pt['Acceleration'] = str(self.acceleration)
        return pt
```

The problem with code is that there is a lot of information duplication going on. First, I duplicate the information that associates keys in the PropertyTree with attributes of `self`, and I also duplicate the keys themselves (`'Speed'` and `'Acceleration'` strings appear twice). Obviously, there's a lot of room for mistakes.

How can I refactor this?

Comment: While DRY is good in principle, repeating something twice doesn't mean you should go write a 20 line generalized solution that still only saves a single line in your actual code.

Comment: @delnan, good point. However, I suspect that he's probably got lots of classes that do this making a generalized solution helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
class Movement(EntityComponent):
    def __init__(self):
        # Default values
        self.speed = 0
        self.acceleration = 0

    serializable_fields = [
        ('speed', int),
        ('acceleration', int)
    ]

def load(object, source):
    for name, field_type in object.serialiable_fields: 
        settarr(object, name, field_type(source[name]))

def save(object):
    target = PropertyTree()
    for name, field_type in object.serializable_fields:
         target[name] = str(getattr(object, name))
    return target
```

Basically, create a separate save/load system, perhaps in the EntityComponent class. Just provide the list of data for the fields to tell the system how to serialize the current object.

If you aren't familiar with it, you could also checkout how Python's pickle module works. I don't recommend using it for anything beyond trivial cases, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: you can store the default as well: `('speed', int, 0)`

Comment: and of course you meant to return the target in the save method.

Comment: Given that you have different cases for your PropertyTree (perhaps these are user-facing names?), you might also want to include this in your serializable_fields tuples.

Comment: Thanks, I went for a different approach, but you're answer inspired me. I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374995/